# Seleccionar todos los campos de una tabla para una subconsulta

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta la cual es la unión de 3 consultas. En la que se juntan todas las ubicaciones hijos y nietos dentro de las ubicaciones padre, es decir:

- padre: URG
- hijos: URG-01, URG-02
- nietos: URG-N-01, URG-N-02

con una consulta y un campo metí a todos dentro de padre y le dije que me diera todas las ubicaciones padre que al final son 34. Pero solo me da 21 por que son las únicas que han tenido transferencias.

Yo no quiero eso, quiero que me muestre las 34, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: si anexas el query con el que lo intentaste, podríamos ayudarte con más facilidad.

Comment: suena a inner join en lugar de left join... como dice @L.Ronquillo, añade el codigo de la query a ver si podemos ayudarte

Comment: Hola de nuevo, pues ya pude hacer eso... pero ahora lo que no puedo es darle un when y decirle que me imprima solo los de grupo A,B,C y aun asi me siga dando las 34 ubicaciones. alguna idea?. :S es en produccion, no se si sea correcto pegar el codigo, ustedes que dicen?

Comment: Ponga el codigo, solo cambie el nombre de las tablas y columnas y ponga solo la parte donde tiene el error y miramos  si le podemos ayudar